# eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped - eth0 stops to work with bridge interface between wlan0 and eth0

Tags: ethernet, bridge

Everything reported in this bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian/+bug/1647397

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you open the URL and read the description you'll find out

Comment: That's a bugzilla, it's not a question at all.